# SQL query to compare 2 tables and output a case statement

Tags: sql, hive

I am trying to write a query that outputs 'Y' if the cust_no is in both tables, else outputs 'N'.

```
Tab_1:
123
456
789

Tab_2:
123
456
896
```

Output:

```
123   Y
456   Y
789   N
```

I understand case statement is needed for this criterion, not sure how does the selection happen. Any heads up would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `full join` to do this.

```
select coalesce(t1.num,t2.num) as num,
case when t1.num is not null and t2.num is not null then 'Y' else 'N' end
from tbl1 t1
full join tbl2 t2 on t1.num=t2.num
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `Left Outer Join`

```
select a.col, 
       case when b.col is null then 'N' else 'Y' end 
from tab_1 a
left Outer join tab_2 b on a.col = b.col
```